# Jackson-databind dependency not working in maven

Tags: java, maven

I want to add Jackson-databind dependency but I still have no jackson classes in my project. I changed my project from gradle to maven and my pom.xml looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>pl.TODOList</groupId>
    <artifactId>TODO_List</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-xml-databind</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
        <jackson.version>2.12.4</jackson.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.13.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

I don't know if my pom.xml is something wrong or something different. I have feeling that is very simple error that I can't see

Comment: Which classes? Is the error occurs in an IDE?

Comment: Move them from `dependencyManagement` to `dependencies`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Then I have the error Dependency 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.4' not found

Comment: `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.4` should be available on Maven central so if your build doesn't find it, maybe your repositories aren't configured properly (or it hasn't been downloaded for some reason).

Comment: Have you tried actually building it, so the dependencies get downloaded? Depending on your IDE this might or might not be automatic.

Comment: @M.Deinum it worked, probably I was misled by some error that occured and I thought that it was due  to dependency.

Answer (score 0):

At first this project using two different artifacts for databinding.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-xml-databind</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

This artifact is an antient one. It released in 2011.

Second, the managed dependencies are not "real"  dependencies. In this case you can imagine managed dependencies as a dependency templates. So, if you want to use a managed dependency as a "real" dependency, then you have to describe those artifacts in `<dependencies></dependencies>` section.

Try something like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>pl.TODOList</groupId>
    <artifactId>TODO_List</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
        <jackson.version>2.12.4</jackson.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope> <!-- Because this used for testing purposes only -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**UPDATE** Based on comment I added the xml databind extension.

Comment: Although the `jackson-xml-databind` is an old one it isn't another databinding it is an extension allowing to also use XML with Jackson instead of only JSON. It is an extension. Although now one should use `jackson-dataformat-xml` instead.

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault. I missed the ```xml``` literal.